# Why does one of the units, namely $50 - 7\sqrt{51}$, in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{51}]$ have a decimal expansion that is the Catalan numbers?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

$50 - 7\sqrt{51}$ is one of the units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{51}]$. In fact, corresponding to $n = 51$, $x = 50$ and $y = 7$ is the [smallest integer solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation#The_smallest_solution_of_Pell_equations) to $x^2 - ny^2 = 1$.

The [Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A000108) have a great deal of combinatorial significance, and they appear in the decimal expansion of  $50 - 7\sqrt{51} \approx 0.010001000200050014004201320429.$

Why is this the case?

Comment: there is likely an answer if we know what function is $$ f(x) = \sum_0^\infty \; C(n) x^n $$

Comment: they say $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) = 1 + x f^2(x)$ so is a complicated recurrence for the power series

Comment: Anyway, your number comes from $x = 1/10000$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wikipedia names $$  c(x) = \sum_0^\infty \; C(n) \; x^n $$
and says that it satisfies
$$ c(x) = 1 + x \, c^2(x)  $$

Define $$   A = c \left( \frac{1}{10000} \right) $$

Then we have
$$  A = 1 + \frac{1}{10000} \; A^2 $$
so
$$  A^2 - 10000A + 10000 = 0. $$ So
$$  A = \frac{10000 \pm \sqrt{100000000 - 40000}}{2} =  \frac{10000 \pm 100 \sqrt{10000 - 4}}{2}$$
$$   A = \frac{10000 \pm 200 \sqrt{2500 - 1}}{2}= 5000 \pm 100 \sqrt {2499} $$
Note $$ 2499 = 51 \cdot 49  $$

Actually, later they say
$$ c(x) = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1 - 4 x}}{2x} = \frac{2}{1 + \sqrt{1 - 4x}} $$
which confirms that we should take 
$$   A = 5000 - 100 \sqrt {2499} = 100 \left( 50 - 7 \sqrt{51} \right)$$